# How to scale HDRI lights?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, scale, hdri

I have a life size scene. But the lighting does not fit the size of the room, it seems that the room is very small

How can this be changed?
P.S
Texture coord.> mapping > env. texture - does not work[image]

[image]

[image]